# How to fix bad substitution error in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to write a bash script where the user enters a class name and it makes the proper `.h` and `.cpp` files.

I have got most of it working however when I run it, I get the error:

> `./makeClass.sh`: line 20: `#include ${className.h}`: bad substitution

The `.h` file is generated with all content as expected whereas the `.cpp` file generation is aborted at that line.

I have tried to replace `${className.h}` with `$(className.h)`, but that did not work.

I also tried to concatenate the strings but I have had no luck.

Thank you for all of your help!

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Please enter the name of the class to be created"
read className

touch $className.h
echo "#include <iostream>" >> $className.h
echo "#ifndef SICT_${className^^}_H" >> $className.h
echo "#define SICT_${className^^}_H" >> $className.h
echo "namespace sict {" >> $className.h
echo "class ${className^} {" >> $className.h
echo " " >> $className.h
echo "public: " >> $className.h
echo " };" >> $className.h
echo "}" >> $className.h
echo "#endif" >> $className.h
# Note: ${className^} converts the first letter to uppercase ${className^^}
# converts the whole string to upper case

touch $className.cpp
echo "#include ${className.h}" >> $className.cpp
echo "#include <iostream>" >> $className.cpp
echo "using namespace sict;" >> $className.cpp
echo "using namespace std;" >> $className.cpp
echo "namespace sict {" >> $className.cpp
echo "" >> $className.cpp
echo "}" >> $className.cpp
```

Error message: ./makeClass.sh: line 20: #include ${className.h}: bad substitution

Comment: try `${className}.h` >> ....`  Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is:

```sh
echo "#include ${className.h}" >> $className.cpp`
                          ^
```

It threats the whole `className.h` as the variable name, and the dot character`.` is not allowed in a variable name.

Also always add the `-r` flag to `read`, unless you want it to interpret escaping.

You can create your templates more clearly and efficiently with here-documents that expands bash variables values:

Although, in case you need to have an actual dollar sign `$` literal, you need to escape it as `\$`, or bash will try to expand a variable name to its value.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Please enter the name of the class to be created"
read -r className

cat <<EndOfClassHeader >"$className.h"
#include <iostream>
#ifndef SICT_${className^^}_H
  #define SICT_${className^^}_H
  namespace sict {
    class ${className^} {

      public:
    };
  }
#endif
EndOfClassHeader

cat <<ENdOfClassCPP >"$className.cpp"
#include ${className}.h
#include <iostream>
using namespace sict;
using namespace std;
namespace sict {
}
ENdOfClassCPP
```

Answer (score 0):

**This will work Always**

```
echo "#include \"$className.h\"" >> $className.cpp
```

> **Explationantion**: As `className.h` is a variable use double-quote when using it and as here there were already double-quotes for `echo`,
>   escape double-quotes for the variable.

**Full Code**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Please enter the name of the class to be created"
read className

touch $className.h
echo "#include <iostream>" >> $className.h
echo "#ifndef SICT_${className^^}_H" >> $className.h
echo "#define SICT_${className^^}_H" >> $className.h
echo "namespace sict {" >> $className.h
echo "class ${className^} {" >> $className.h
echo " " >> $className.h
echo "public: " >> $className.h
echo " };" >> $className.h
echo "}" >> $className.h
echo "#endif" >> $className.h
# Note: ${className^} converts the first letter to uppercase ${className^^}
# converts the whole string to upper case

touch $className.cpp
echo "#include \"$className.h\"" >> $className.cpp
echo "#include <iostream>" >> $className.cpp
echo "using namespace sict;" >> $className.cpp
echo "using namespace std;" >> $className.cpp
echo "namespace sict {" >> $className.cpp
echo "" >> $className.cpp
echo "}" >> $className.cpp
```